# How to treat an image in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I want to work with an image that you take with camera, explicitly, I want work with matrix image, change pixel...
That's my code which allow you to take a picture.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showImagePicker: Bool = false
    @State private var image: Image? = nil




    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            image?.resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .padding(.top,100)
                .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300.0, alignment: .top)


            Button(action: {self.showImagePicker = true

            }) {HStack {
                Image(systemName: "camera.on.rectangle.fill")
                    .font(.title)
                Text("Take picture")
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .font(.title)
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(40)}





        }
        .padding(.bottom,400)
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$showImagePicker) {
            PhotoCaptureView(showImagePicker: self.$showImagePicker, image: self.$image)
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()

    }
}
```

Here is PhotoCaptureView

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct PhotoCaptureView: View {

    @Binding var showImagePicker: Bool
    @Binding var image: Image?

    var body: some View {
        ImagePicker(isShown: $showImagePicker, image: $image)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct PhotoCaptureView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PhotoCaptureView(showImagePicker: .constant(false), image: .constant(Image("")))
    }
}
#endif
```

I have to return the image, I guess that it is in struct PhotoCaptureView.

How to retrieve this image and work with ?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to return UIImage from PhotoCaptureView instead of Image, because there is no way to get back UIImage from Image.

Comment: can you show us your photocapturefview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onDismiss` completionHandler of the sheet to work on image after it is selected.

```
.sheet(isPresented: Binding<Bool>.constant(true), onDismiss: {
            if let image = self.image {
                processor.process(image)
            }
        }, content: { () -> View in
            PhotoCaptureView(showImagePicker: self.$showImagePicker, image: self.$image)
        })
```